# could not create Unix-domain socket in directory "/var/run/postgresql"

Tags: postgresql, unix-socket

I try to uncomment 'unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'  in postgresql.conf.

But after doing that, when I try to restart postgresql, I receive

```
  Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See 
  "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Looking for journalctl, I see:

```
LOG:  could not bind Unix socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, remove socket file 
"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL...and retry.
: WARNING:  could not create Unix-domain socket in directory "/var/run/postgresql"
```

Full stack:

```
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; 
 vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Ср 2020-01-29 13:39:52 MSK; 
 27s ago
  Process: 2937 ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctl stop -D ${PGDATA} -s -m fast 
 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2550 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o -p 
 ${PGPORT} -w -t 300 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2544 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} 
 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2554 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

   plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
   plesk.iline.pro pg_ctl[2550]: LOG:  could not bind Unix socket: 
   Address already in use
   plesk.iline.pro pg_ctl[2550]: HINT:  Is another postmaster already 
   running on port 5432? If not, remove socket file 
   "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL...and retry.
    plesk.iline.pro pg_ctl[2550]: WARNING:  could not create Unix- 
    domain socket in directory "/var/run/postgresql"
    plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL database server.
    2 plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: postgresql.service: main process 
    exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
    plesk.iline.pro pg_ctl[2937]: pg_ctl: could not send stop signal 
    (PID: 2554): No such process
    plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control process 
    exited, code=exited status=1
    plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed 
    state.
    plesk.iline.pro systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version is that?

Comment: version PostgreSQL  is 9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely there is another PostgreSQL server running on the same port.

You should do what PostgreSQL recommends:

```
ls -l /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

There should be a socket file present.

Then, as user `root`, see if there is a PostgreSQL process listening on the port:

```
sudo fuser /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

If there is a result, there is really another PostgreSQL server running on port 5432. Either stop that server or choose a different port for your cluster.

If there is no result, the socket may be left over. Remove it and try again.

Comment: I have no result after running this commands.  And how can I remove socket. I have tried 'rm .s.PGSQL.5432', but receive 'failed to remove  .s.PGSQL.5432 as its a directory

Comment: What does "no result" mean? An error "no such file or directory"? Something else? Details, please.

Comment: After ls -l /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432   next line retrieve 0.

Comment: After sudo fuser /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432     next line is empty.

Comment: "retrieve 0" doesn't make much sense to me. Kill all PostgreSQL processes on the machine, remove `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` and try again.

Comment: And how can I remove /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432    ?

Comment: There is a command called `rm` for that: `sudo rm -f /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

Comment: Tried this, but receive ' failed to remove .s.PGSQL.5432 as its a directory'